# How to assign data to node of VirtualStringTree in InitNode event

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I am not sure how to assign data to a node in a VirtualStringTree. I'm need to assign a pointer to a record object to the Node's Data property in the tree control's InitNode event. However I'm getting a 'Pointer type required' compile-time error.

```
type
  TDiagData = record
    DiagID: Integer;
    DiagName: String;
    Selected: Byte;
  end;

  PDiagData = ^TDiagData;

var
  FDiagDataList: TObjectList;
  c: Integer; // used as an iterator for the list // incremented in vst1InitNode



procedure Btn1Click;
var
  DiagData : PDiagData;
begin

  try
    FDiagDataList := TObjectList.Create; // TODO: Move this to form constructor

    for c := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      New(DiagData);

      DiagData.DiagID := c;
      DiagData.DiagName := Format('Diag# %d', [c]);

      FDiagDataList.Add(DiagData);
    end;

    c := 0;

    vst1.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TDiagData);
    vst1.RootNodeCount := 10; // test

  finally
    //  FDiagDataList.Free;   //TODO: Move this to form destructor
  end
end;

procedure vst1InitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; ParentNode, Node: PVirtualNode;
  var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
var
  DiagData: PDiagData;
begin

  DiagData = TDiagData(FDiagDataList.Items[c]); // FDiagDataList is a TObjectlist

  Node.Data^ := DiagData; // <--- this is not working ..
  // The error is: Pointer type required.

  Inc(c);
end;
```

I need to assign the data to the node in the InitNode event, but not am sure how to assign it.

Comment: I can guess what the compiler error is, but to be didactic, can you please edit the question to include the compiler error. I actually think that you have two distinct errors here. But it would be better for you to tell us what they are.

Comment: `DiagData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node); DiagData.DiagID := ...` or `DiagData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node); DiagData^ := FDiagDataList.Items[c]` but what is `c` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not read or write `Node.Data` directly. The data *you* need won't necessarily be exactly at the address of that field. (The tree control has a mechanism for allowing descendants to reserve additional data for themselves.) Instead, call `Sender.GetNodeData`.

```
var
  NodeData: PDiagData;
begin
  NodeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  NodeData^ := TDiagData(FDiagDataList.Items[c]);
end;
```

Your code fails because `Node.Data` has type `record`; you cannot dereference it with `^`. In the simple case, the value returned by `GetNodeData` will be equal to the address of that field (i.e., `GetNodeData(Node) = @Node.Data`). But don't assume all cases are simple. As I said, tree-control descendants can reserve data space of their own, so you're *sharing* that space with code that's outside your control, and it's up to the tree control to manage *which* data space is yours. Always call `GetNodeData`.

---

Furthermore, you're confused about your data types. You say `FDiagDataList` is a `TObjectList`, but you're clearly storing something in it that *isn't* a descendant of `TObject`. When you're not using objects, don't use `TObjectList`. If you're using a version of Delphi earlier than 2009, then use `TList` and store *pointers* to `TDiagData`:

```
NodeData^ := PDiagData(FDiagDataList[c])^;
```

If you're using Delphi 2009 or later, then use `TList<TDiagData>`, and then get rid of the type cast:

```
NodeData^ := FDiagDataList[c];
```

Either way, you'll probably find things easier to manage if *every* event handler starts out the same way, with a call to `GetNodeData` to fetch the type-safe pointer to the current node's data.

Comment: Eeek! That `c` is still with us.

Comment: So what, @Tlama? We could replace it with some meta-expression, *`expression-that-selects-data-for-current-node`*, but we can also assume that *`c`* already *is* such an expression. Why be wordier?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Good and relevant answer.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I would expect you to explain what the c can be in that context. Steve, what is that c in real ?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Why do you say "NodeData^ := FDiagDataList[c];"? Shouldn't it be "NodeData := FDiagDataList[c];"?

Comment: Definitely not, Steve. I already assigned that *local variable* on the previous line. Now I want to assign the memory that the local variable *points at*.

Comment: @RobKennedy Hi Rob, there's something really wrong with my code and the pointers / addresses. I'm making a new question now.